# Jquery find a class within a nested function

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am relatively new to jQuery and am having a few issues with selecting the correct element within a function after an animation completes.

To put it simply, when the animation has finished I would like a class to be added to an element within the page. This is what I have so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#lightsout').fadeTo(1000, 1,
            function(){
                $('.text404').addclass('lightsout');
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

I would be greatful if someone could show the correct way of going about doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.addClass()` must have an uppercase **C**

Comment: Ahhhh man! Rookie error! Was on the jQuery website looking as well. Thanks for pointing out the error of my ways.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#lightsout').fadeTo(1000, 1,
            function(){
                $('.text404').addClass('lightsout');
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

The mistake is, you have incorrectly spelt `addClass`

Comment: Check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/), that `, 1` is required.

Comment: @Simon My mistake. Corrected.